# JS Ajax request results in "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: php, ajax, linux

Even though you might think it is, this is not a duplicate post, atleast I haven´t been able to find another thread dealing with this particular problem.

Here is the problem.

We are working on one of our client´s websites where we use this basic JS ajax call to fetch data from a PHP file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/pathtofile/my-ajax-handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { field1: "value" },
        success: function (response) {
        jQuery("div.mycontainer").attr("data-update", response);
        },
        error: function () {
            //your error code
        }
    });
```

The target PHP file is a simple script that performs a curl and returns a value from header response. It does not use the POST parameter provided in the ajax call, so I am able to get the data by simply entering the URL to the PHP file directly in the browser, which works without any PHP or Apache server errors..

The PHP file looks like this example:

```
<?php
function getheaderdatafromcurl($string, $start, $finish) {
    $string = " ".$string;
    $position = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($position == 0) return "";
    $position += strlen($start);
    $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
    return substr($string, $position, $length);
}

$apiURL= 'https://path-to.api.com/apipath/api?limit=1&start=0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

$totalcount = trim(getheaderdatafromcurl($header, "Total-Results:", "Link:"));

if($totalcount > 0) {
echo $totalcount;
}
?>
```

As I mentioned the PHP script returns the value without any errors when I execute the file directly from my browser.
But when the ajax call tries to fetch the value it shows "500 (Internal Server Error)" in Chrome dev panel.

Also, we have tried to copy the entire website over to our own test server, and there everything works without any errors, including the ajax call.
We have also made sure that the root .htaccess is identical on both webservers.

Apparently it seems like the problem is caused by some problematic / incompatible server configuration on our client´s hosting service, but I have never experienced this particular problem before.

My client´s base webserver info:
System: Linux
Build date: Jan 20 2017 03:18:35
Server API: CGI/FastCGI

I hope someone out there can help me figure this one out.

---

**UPDATE!**

As a temporary (maybe permanent) solution we decided to move the website to another hosting provider, where there are no problems.

Meanwhile, we would still like to know what could be the possible reasons for this error occurring on the original webserver.

As mentioned the problem is not in the PHP file itself, e.g. usage of unsupported functions etc.
When opened directly in browser the PHP script executes without errors.
The problem is specifically when performing the ajax call and only on the original webserver.

We have not been able to re-create the problem on another webserver.

Comment: You've got an **internal** server error. Look at the server logs and see what the error message is!

Comment: We have done that, and nothing to find there..

Comment: Maybe file rights?. Anyways change the /pathtofile/my-ajax-handler.php to allow $_GET values, and check it with a simple browser passing parameters. If it works then ajax must work, if not, you will get code 500.

Comment: Nah, I don´t think thats the problem. I have tried to add URL parameters to the URL to the PHP file and opening it directly in browser, and no error. 
Anyways, this still wouldn´t explain why the ajax call works on our dev server and not on the clients´ server.

Comment: @hamboy75  - More to the point.. file rights wouldn´t explain why there are no errors when executing the PHP script directly in browser. The ajax call should have the same access rights as when someone opens the file directly in browser.